# Add, Update and Delete jQuery code didn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I'm only new on jQuery so it is very difficult for me to understand it. So I try some code from the other website. When I try it to my browser. It only show the table header no jQuery at all. I put the jQuery library. No more error like this one "ReferenceError: $ is not defined". There something wrong with the code?

```js
$(function(){
    //Add, Save, Edit and Delete functions code
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
});

function Add(){
    $("#tblData tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><img src='person1.png' class='btnSave'><img src='person1.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+
        "</tr>");
     
        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);      
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}; 
function Save(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
 
    tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdButtons.html("<img src='person1.png' class='btnDelete'/><img src='person1.png' class='btnEdit'/>");
 
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}; 
function Edit(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
 
    tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='"+tdName.html()+"'/>");
    tdPhone.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='"+tdPhone.html()+"'/>");
    tdEmail.html("<input type='text' id='txtEmail' value='"+tdEmail.html()+"'/>");
    tdButtons.html("<img src='person1.png' class='btnSave'/>");
 
    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};
function Delete(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    par.remove();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAdd”>New</button>
    <table id="tblData">          
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To the point, you definately have logic errors in your code, because you are adding 'click' listeners in every action on ALL buttons, even on those, that are already have it, but only to the fresh-added buttons. So your buttons will call, for example, Add() function several times once clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Try, wrapping your code in to be sure, that it is in it's own scope and is executed when the document is ready for javascript manipulations:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // ... your code here;
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not loading well the jquery framework because it doesn't find it.

Try to add "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" in the src of your  tag. Or just create the .js file in your server.

```js
$(function(){
    //Add, Save, Edit and Delete functions code
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
});

function Add(){
    $("#tblData tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><img src='person1.png' class='btnSave'><img src='person1.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+
        "</tr>");
     
        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);      
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}; 
function Save(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
 
    tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdButtons.html("<img src='person1.png' class='btnDelete'/><img src='person1.png' class='btnEdit'/>");
 
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}; 
function Edit(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
 
    tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='"+tdName.html()+"'/>");
    tdPhone.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='"+tdPhone.html()+"'/>");
    tdEmail.html("<input type='text' id='txtEmail' value='"+tdEmail.html()+"'/>");
    tdButtons.html("<img src='person1.png' class='btnSave'/>");
 
    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};
function Delete(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    par.remove();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAdd">New</button>
    <table id="tblData">          
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: he character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: Check it out now @DavePH I haven't seen that there was an incorrect double quotation mark in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the quotation mark on

```
 <button id="btnAdd">New</button>
```

Also to ensure that your js code runs after the jquery loads, keep it just before the body closing tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btnAdd">New</button>
  <table id="tblData">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      //Add, Save, Edit and Delete functions code
      $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
      $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
      $("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
    });

    function Add() {
      $("#tblData tbody").append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>" +
        "<td><img alt='Save' src='person1.png' class='btnSave'><img alt='Delete' src='person1.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>" +
        "</tr>");

      $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
      $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    };

    function Save() {
      var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
      var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
      var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
      var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
      var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

      tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
      tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
      tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=text]").val());
      tdButtons.html("<img alt='Delte' src='person1.png' class='btnDelete'/><img src='person1.png' alt='Edit' class='btnEdit'/>");

      $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
      $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    };

    function Edit() {
      var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
      var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
      var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
      var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
      var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

      tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='" + tdName.html() + "'/>");
      tdPhone.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='" + tdPhone.html() + "'/>");
      tdEmail.html("<input type='text' id='txtEmail' value='" + tdEmail.html() + "'/>");
      tdButtons.html("<img alt='Save' src='person1.png' class='btnSave'/>");

      $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
      $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
      $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    };

    function Delete() {
      var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
      par.remove();
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is possibility that I can used jQuery offline? How?

Comment: Yes just download it and keep it along with your html and give its relative path in src.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you copied this code from other place.So there has something you need to change in order to make it right.

First- the script you included it has to be in your local directory otherwise your browser wont find the jQuery.

```js
 $(function(){
    //Add, Save, Edit and Delete functions code
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
});

function Add(){
    $("#tblData tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><img src='person1.png' class='btnSave'><img src='person1.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+
        "</tr>");
     
        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);      
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}; 
function Save(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
 
    tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdButtons.html("<img src='person1.png' class='btnDelete'/><img src='person1.png' class='btnEdit'/>");
 
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}; 
function Edit(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
 
    tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='"+tdName.html()+"'/>");
    tdPhone.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='"+tdPhone.html()+"'/>");
    tdEmail.html("<input type='text' id='txtEmail' value='"+tdEmail.html()+"'/>");
    tdButtons.html("<img src='person1.png' class='btnSave'/>");
 
    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};
function Delete(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    par.remove();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAdd">New</button> <!--in this line one error: btnAdd double quote"-->
    <table id="tblData">          
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   </body>
  </html>
```

If  you dont have it in your local directory then include the virtual library.

Hope this will help.